# want to use updateMessage("...") in a Class that is not an Task

Tags: javafx, task

I want to use updateMessage("...") in a Class that is not an Task.
How can I solve this Problem?
Is it possible to give a Task Handle which can perform a updateMessage("...") to a Function?

```
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

public class TestTask extends Task<Void> {
   private final static int COUNT = 1000;

   @Override
   protected Void call() {
      doTaskStuff("Found ");
      return null;
   }

   public void doTaskStuff(String s) {
      for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
         System.out.println(i);
         this.updateProgress(i, COUNT);
         this.updateMessage(s + (i + 1) + "!");
         Dummy.dummy(this, i);
         try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
         } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
         }
      }
   }
}

class Dummy {
   public static void dummy(TestTask testTask, int i) {
      String s = "";
      if (i == 0) {
         s = "i == 0";
      } else {
         s = "i != 0";
      }
      testTask.updateMessage(s);// does not work
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is the method being `protected`. Of course you could override the method and increase the visibility, but this would imho be a bad approach:

```
@Override
public void updateMessage(String message) {
    super.updateMessage(message);
}
```

---

Note that the method sets a single message, therefore you could just return the value:

```
updateMessage(Dummy.dummy(i));
```

```
public static String dummy(int i) {
    return (i == 0) ? "i == 0" : "i != 0";
}
```

---

For multiple updates you could also provide access to this kind of functionality using an interface:

```
Dummy.dummy(this::updateMessage, i);
```

```
public static void dummy(Consumer<String> updater, int i) {
    updater.accept((i == 0) ? "i == 0" : "i != 0");
}
```